# Pull User Profile Info From TFS

Tags: api, tfs

I am trying to use API to pull user profile info from Microsoft TFS for work. What they have posted, how many hours they have logged, etc. I have little to no experience coding so right now any Any help will be most appreciated!

Comment: TFS is not a time tracking system

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Data Warehouse and Cube to get the reports that you are looking for. There are many ways to manage the data; Reporting Services, Excel, or custom.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647430.aspx